# Can't Catch Error for Mongoose Model Save

Tags: node.js, validation, mongoose

I have a simple user schema:

### /schemas/user.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var userSchema = new Schema({
  username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
  group: String,
  created_at: Date,
  updated_at: Date
});

var User = mongoose.model(
  'User',
  userSchema
);

module.exports = User;
```

And an index page with a form that is capable of creating a user. I want to display a flash message to the user if the save does not work properly. I know the premise to do this is to create a place for the message in the `get` route and if the message exists, then render a dom element containing the message. Unfortunately all that I can manage is to crash the server and receive:

### Error message

```
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
BulkWriteError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.users index: email_1 dup key: { : "test@gmail.com" }
    at /home/bob/sites/mysite.ca/projects/login/node_modules/mongodb/lib/bulk/unordered.js:528:15
    at handleCallback (/home/bob/sites/mysite.ca/projects/login/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:128:55)
    at resultHandler (/home/bob/sites/mysite.ca/projects/login/node_modules/mongodb/lib/bulk/unordered.js:454:5)
    at /home/bob/sites/mysite.ca/projects/login/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:541:18
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

### /routes/index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function() {
  console.log('index.js db connected!');
});

var User = require('../schemas/user');

router.post('/create', function(req, res, next) {
  var user = new User({
    username: req.body.username,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password
  });
  user.save(function(error) {
    if (error) console.log(error);
    console.log('User ' + user.username + ' successfully created!');
  });
});

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render(
    'index',
    {
        title: 'Express'
    }
  );
});

module.exports = router;
```

How can I catch this error and handle it rather than crashing the node server?

Comment: You are getting `BulkWriteError` which means somewhere in your code you are executing a bulk write operation, maybe the error stacktrace can help to find the exact portion of code throwing this error

Comment: Indeed you are correct, I do see the stack trace but it looks like it's originating from some internal file, not one that I created. I will update the post to include the full error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your code is correct, you just need to create mongoose connection in `app.js` only once, by default mongoose use a pool of 5 simultaneous connections and there is no need to create a connection in each router:

**app.js**

```
...
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');
...
```

**routes/index.js**

And you have to send response to the client to terminate the request-response cycle, otherwise the client will be left hanging:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var User = require('../schemas/user');
...

router.post('/create', function(req, res, next) {
    var user = new User(req.body);
    user.save(function(err, user) {
        if (err) return res.json(err);
        res.send('User ' + user.username + ' successfully created!');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

in the user model you're setting the **username** and **email** as *unique* types, and the error said that the value containing the **"test@gmail.com"** is duplicated(it already exists) as its type is unique.
So check your posts data to not be duplicated and reset your DB then try.

try this method i think it should prevent your node to crash:

```
router.post('/create', async(req, res, next) => {
  try {
    var user = new User({
      username: req.body.username,
      email: req.body.email,
      password: req.body.password
    });

    var created = await user.save();
    res.send({ result: created })
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error', error);
    res.send({ error });
  }
});
```

Comment: I understand that the error message is valid, but instead of crashing the server I want to capture that error and display it to the user as stated in my original question

Comment: Yes, so you just need to catch the error inside a try/catch then return the error to the user, i'll update the response.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer matching the exception name and code to identify what kind of error it is

```
    try {
    var user = new User({
      username: req.body.username,
      email: req.body.email,
      password: req.body.password
    });

    var created = await user.save();
    res.send({ result: created })
    } catch (exception) {
      if (exception.name === 'MongoError' && exception.code === 11000) {
       res.send({ exception });
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case if someone has issues in catching the error in try catch with async:

```
router.post('/create', async (req, res)=>{
  const user = new User(req.body);
  try {
    return user.save();
  }catch(e){
    if(e && e.code === 11000) {
      throw DuplicateError();
    }
    throw e;
  }

});
```

We want to send a custom error/message if there is a duplicate key error. The catch in the example above will not work.
Because we return user.save() we return a promise that will be awaited somewhere else. (usually done in that way so we can format the response in a middleware). Because it is awaited elsewhere, the code that does error-catching here is irrelevant.

To make it work all we have to do is await the response.

```
return await user.save()
```